# What is the easiest way to output a dataset with out using a grid view with ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to output my MySQL query to a li tag full of tables my select statement is working, I am just using the sample DB from MySQL world cities, my question is what is the simplest way to access individual rows and columns? Should I create a new Class or struct to push the data into? I want to be able to convert the data table into something like a List of HashTables? should I use something like JSON.net?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MySQL
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connStr = "server=localhost;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=world; Password=root";
        MySqlDataAdapter countries;
        DataSet ds;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
            countries = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(countries);

            ds = new DataSet();
            countries.Fill(ds, "Country");

        }
    }
}
```

I am very well versed with jquery, javascript, angularjs, I am not concerned about the html output but I want to know whats the easiest way to access the individual columns? and rows to output them?

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try the ListView for cleaner markup. Why are you avoiding the GridView?

Comment: grid view is auto formatted I don't really know how to use it and the main thing is I need to format the data as a comments/ratings page gridview from what i know (which is not much) is dipslay in a format that is similar to a excel spreadsheet format which is not what I need.

Comment: Whoah I didn't know that ASP.net has a repeater template thats really interesting I may use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to access all tables by row and columns.

Do this

```
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
      string sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
      countries = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
      MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(countries);

      ds = new DataSet();
      countries.Fill(ds, "Country");
      DataTable dt;
      for (int i = 0; i <ds.Tables.Count; i++)//traverse by each table in dataset
      {
           dt = ds.Tables[i];

           for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)//traverse by row
           {
                Response.Write("Current Row--> "+j.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
                object[] ob = dt.Rows[j].ItemArray; // get array of column from present row
                for (int k = 0; k <= ob.GetUpperBound(0); k++)
                {
                     Response.Write("Current column Number--> "+k.ToString()+" Value = "+ob[k].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
                }
           }

      }
```